# Computing losing positions in modified Wythoff's game efficiently

Tags: number-theory, game-theory

> [Wythoff's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wythoff%27s_game) game is as follows: there are two players $A$ and $B$ ( $A$ being the first player ) and there are $2$ piles of stones. When his turn a player can remove one or more stones from anyone pile or same number of stones from both the piles. A player unable to make a move loses. Also it is assumed that both the players play optimally.

As mentioned in the link the losing configurations $(n_k,m_k)$ ( $n_k$ stones in one pile and $m_k$ stones in another ) are given by
$$ n_k = \lfloor( k*\phi) \rfloor$$
$$ m_k = \lfloor( k*\phi^2) \rfloor$$
where $k$ is any natural number ( and $n_k \le m_k$ ) and $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. For example $\{1,2\}$ ( two stones in one pile and one stone in another ) is a losing position.

**Modification to Wythoff's game"**

In this modified game instead of ${\it2}$ piles there are ${\it 3}$ piles. And when his turn a player can move one or more stones from anyone pile or same number of stones from any $2$ piles or same number of stones from all the $3$ piles. 
How do I compute the losing positions for this modified game efficiently ? The inefficient way of course is to find the [grundy number](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/algorithm-games/) of each  configuration $\{a,b,c\}$. This method is inefficient because I want to calculate  number of losing positions given that number of stones in each pile can be between $1$ and $1000$.

This is a project Euler question ( [stone game](https://projecteuler.net/problem=260) ). I would appreciate hints
only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no closed form for $n=3$ piles. But one can solve the question efficiently using dynamic programming.

Comment: Good self-service ;) Could you elaborate your answer a bit (about no closed form)? (I have seen your question, but wanted to give more time).